# Code Coverage 70% but I can't figure out how to make it to 75% or 100%

Tags: apex, trigger, error, code-coverage, duplicate-management

I am new to triggers.  I will admit that but this is my first trigger and I really want it to work!  My problem is that I still am receiving only 70% Code Coverage when the trigger works fine in sandbox but when I click into each one of these colored lines below I receive the same Duplication error.  Thank you all ahead of time.

**Duplication Error:**
To get this error message to display I doubeclicked on top of one of the line numbers.  Is that the proper way to display what is wrong?
[image]

**Trigger with Code Coverage Issues Highlighted:**

[image]

**Trigger minus Highlights**

```
trigger checkForCompetitors on Opportunity (before update) {
Set<Id> closedLostOppIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> oppsHavingCompetitors = new Set<Id>();

 // fetch all the Opportunity Id's that have been closed
 for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
 {
      if(trigger.OldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName != 'Closed Lost'
         && (opp.StageName == 'Closed Lost') && (opp.Reasons_for_Lost_Opportunity__c.contains('Competition')))
      {
            closedLostOppIds.add(opp.Id);
      }
 }

 // fetch Opportunity Id's that have been Closed Lost and have a Competitor
 for(OpportunityCompetitor oc : [Select OpportunityId From OpportunityCompetitor Where OpportunityId IN : closedLostOppIds ])
 {
      oppsHavingCompetitors.add(oc.OpportunityId);
 }

 // compare the two sets (one has Closed Lost opportunity id's and other has Closed Lost opps having a competitor)
 // Left out opp's should not be allowed to close, so we throw an error.
 for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)
 {
       if(closedLostOppIds.contains(o.Id) && !oppsHavingCompetitors.contains(o.Id))
            o.addError('At least one competitor is required before closing this Opportunity');
 }
 }
```

**Test Class**

```
 @isTest
 private class Test_checkForCompetitors {
 static testMethod void checkForCompetitors() {


// Create a test account
  Account testAcct = new Account (Name = 'My Test Account');
  insert testAcct;

  // Create a test opportunity
  Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity( Name = 'My Test Opp1',
                              AccountId = testAcct.Id,
                              StageName = 'Closed Lost',
                              CloseDate = System.today(),
                              Reasons_for_Lost_Opportunity__c = 'Competition',
                              Next_Steps__c = 'This is only a Test',          
                              LeadSource = 'Web Lead',          
                              Purchase_Cadence__c = 'Annualized');

  insert  testOpp;

   // Get the opportunity, verify the stage name and close date
  testOpp = [SELECT StageName, Name, CloseDate, Reasons_for_Lost_Opportunity__c, Next_Steps__c, LeadSource, Purchase_Cadence__c
             FROM Opportunity 
             WHERE id = :testOpp.Id];

   System.assertEquals(testOpp.StageName, 'Closed Lost');
   System.assertEquals(testOpp.Name, 'My Test Opp1');
   System.assertEquals(testOpp.CloseDate, System.today());
   System.assertEquals(testOpp.Reasons_for_Lost_Opportunity__c, 'Competition');
   System.assertEquals(testOpp.Next_Steps__c, 'This is only a Test');
   System.assertEquals(testOpp.LeadSource, 'Web Lead');
   System.assertEquals(testOpp.Purchase_Cadence__c, 'Annualized');

   } 
   }
```

Comment: That Duplicate Id error is a red herring. The issue is with your testmethod, as noted in the Answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger is on before update but your test is only doing an insert of opportunities. Try creating the opportunities and the opportunity competitors associated with them, then modify the stage and update those opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your test is not actually testing the functionality of your trigger, which only runs on before update of an Opportunity. To actually test your trigger, you'll need to insert an opportunity in your test that is Closed Lost and then update to not Closed Lost making sure that Reasons_for_Lost_Opportunity__c.contains('Competition')